# using google web components with polymer

Tags: polymer, web-component, google-web-component

I am using google web components from the following page but it seems that it has a lot of error. A lot of file is not found. Note: I am using google sign in and google analytics.
[Google Web Components](https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents)

How to resolve the issue without downloading and replace the the missing file path one by one?

Answer (score 2):

You approach is completely wrong.

**TL;DR** One can not simply refer the url for the file and hope that relative paths in it are resolved automagically. The workflow is a way more complicated.

You should create an application (the easiest way is to [use Yeoman’s generator](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/yeoman/) for that). Than you should explicitly specify, which components you want to use with `bower`:

```
bower install google-calendar --save
... etc
```

That would install the components locally (`--save` is to update your `bower.json`).

Then you probably would vulcanize everything (thanks yeoman generator, grunt script comes with all the tasks prepared.) Your project is now ready to deploy.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's not package.json, but bower.json.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install the missing dependency components the same way you got your Google Web Component. Whether that is via download or bower or whatever, just make sure the relative paths line up. Even if you create a build task or generator you will still need the components dependencies correctly referenced.